# I am getting null values im my servlet when i do? it is different from others as i am not getting any answer for it?

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
       String store = "";
        String description = request.getParameter("desc");
        System.out.println(description);
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        System.out.println(title);
    String fileName = request.getParameter("file_name");
        System.out.println(fileName);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        Part file = request.getPart("file");
        if (file != null) {
            inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        }
        String taskPriority = request.getParameter("priority");
        int priority = Integer.parseInt(taskPriority);
        System.out.println("priority");
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        Date chosenDate;
        Date endDate;
        try {
            chosenDate = date.parse(request.getParameter("sdate"));
            System.out.println(chosenDate);
            endDate = date.parse(request.getParameter("ddate"));
            System.out.println(endDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] stores = request.getParameterValues("store");
        for (int i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
            store += stores[i] + " ";
            System.out.println(store);
        }


    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="create-task" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>TaskId</label><input type="text" name="task_id">  <label>title</label><input
                    type="text" name="title"><label>description</label><input
                    type="text" name="desc"> <label>priority</label> <select
                    class="form-control" type="text" name="priority">
                    <option>Urgent</option>
                    <option>Medium</option>
                    <option>Low</option>
                </select> <label>File</label><input type="file" name="file"> <label>FileName</label><input
                    type="text" name="file_name"> <label>start&nbsp;Date</label><input
                    type="text" name="sdate"> <label>due&nbsp;Date</label><input
                    type="text" name="ddate"> <label>Stores</label> <select
                    name="stores" multiple>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>




    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 26, 2018 12:44:22 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 26, 2018 12:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2018 12:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2018 12:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4307 ms
null
null
null
Mar 26, 2018 12:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CreateTaskServlet] in context with path [/StoreManagement] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.azilen.storemanagement.controller.CreateTaskServlet.doPost(CreateTaskServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


----------
```

this is my servlet and it is getting null values from the jsp page.please help me please help me for the above code why am i getting this null.this is my jsp page for the particular servlet.if it is coming then why it is coming i am not getting any reason. here are the console errors in the jsp pages.

Comment: Can you show the complete output? There are quite some `System.out.println()` lines. Which one is showing the `NULL` values?

Comment: do you want console output

Comment: @BalusC it the different from others as  i have gone through each and every code in stackoverflow